# Dynamic image ng-src doesn't change to minified image name

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, minify, grunt-usemin, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I've got two images, a green check mark and a grey check mark. These are shown/hidden as the user checks or unchecks an item in a list. The problem I'm having is that when minifying the app's images with `grunt-contrib-imagemin`, these two images `ng-src` doesn't change to the minified image name. Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

```
<img ng-if="item.checkedState === 'unchecked'" ng-src="images/unchecked.png" ng-click="changeCheckedState(item)">
<img ng-if="item.checkedState === 'checked'" ng-src="images/checked.png" ng-click="changeCheckedState(item)">
```

My usemin task:

```
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** By testing @Tony Barnes solution:

```
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'],
    patterns: {
    html: [
        [/<img[^\>]*[^\>\S]+ng-src=[""]([^'"\)#]+)(#.+)?["']/gm, 'Update the HTML with non standard ng-src attribute on img']
    ]
    }
  }
}
```

The other src names for scripts and styles fails, i.e. the file `vendors132918.js` becomes `vendor.js` in the `src` which then throws a `404 not found` error since the file isn't called `vendor.js`. What is causing the other `src`'s to fail here? The pattern shouldn't change anything except for the src on images as far as I can see..

Comment: It looks like the images will get minified because `imagemin` is watching everything in the `images/` directory. Are you sure they are not in the directory? Maybe, depending on your setup, after minifying, the image's are renamed and your `ng-src`'s are not updated with the new file name.

Comment: @TonyBarnes All images are in there, the images themselves are getting minified but the source doesn't change to the minified ones. Maybe I was a bit unclear.

Comment: Do you have a usemin task in your grunt setup? Are other images renamed in the HTML after minifying?

Comment: @TonyBarnes Yes and yes, other images gets minified and have their source renamed accordingly. But as soon as I use ng-if or ng-show/hide then it doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting, can you post your usemin task?

Comment: How would the pattern change if my HTML looked like this? `<img class="icon" ng-class="getIcon(mot.TransportationMode)" ng-src="images/{{getIcon(mot.TransportationMode)}}.svg">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue lays with the `grunt-usemin` task that replaces the references. By default, `ng-src` is ignored by usemin.

If you include this `html` pattern, the `ng-src` references will be replaced correctly.

```
usemin: {
  options: {
    patterns: {
      html: [

        [/<img[^\>]*[^\>\S]+ng-src=[""]([^'"\)#]+)(#.+)?["']/gm, 'Update the HTML with non standard ng-src attribute on img']

      ]
    }
  }
}
```

(Inspired by this [recent commit](https://github.com/AstroDigital/libra/commit/3909a16a8cba39e3b317bdd5e5fd44c3473e8cef))

**However,** this breaks other references to styles and scripts. It seems that other default `usemin` patterns are overridden by the above addition.

To get this all working, you need to combine the above pattern and the default pattern's from `usemin`:

```
options: {
    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'],
    patterns: {
      html: [
         [/(images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm,
         'Update the angular directives that ref revved images'],

         //defaults from node module
         [ /<script.+src=['"]([^"']+)["']/gm,
         'Update the HTML to reference our concat/min/revved script files'
         ],
         [ /<link[^\>]+href=['"]([^"']+)["']/gm,
         'Update the HTML with the new css filenames'
         ],
         [ /<img[^\>]+src=['"]([^"']+)["']/gm,
         'Update the HTML with the new img filenames'
         ],
         [ /data-main\s*=['"]([^"']+)['"]/gm,
         'Update the HTML with data-main tags',
         function (m) { return m.match(/\.js$/) ? m : m + '.js'; },
         function (m) { return m.replace('.js', ''); }
         ],
         [ /data-(?!main).[^=]+=['"]([^'"]+)['"]/gm,
         'Update the HTML with data-* tags'
         ],
         [ /url\(\s*['"]([^"']+)["']\s*\)/gm,
         'Update the HTML with background imgs, case there is some inline style'
         ],
         [ /<a[^\>]+href=['"]([^"']+)["']/gm,
         'Update the HTML with anchors images'
         ],
         [/<input[^\>]+src=['"]([^"']+)["']/gm,
         'Update the HTML with reference in input'
         ]
       ],
      js: [
          [/(images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 
          'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried adding patterns like you suggested but I received a warning: "Unsupported pattern: patterns". I also posted my original usemin.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Sorry, patterns should be inside the `options` object - updated. I hope it works!

Comment: It seems as if this pattern causes all scripts and styles rewrites to fail, because I get a bunch of 404 errors when trying to load those resources when including your solution. Any idea why?

Comment: I'm not sure off hand - later I will look at re-creating the issue :)

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I replicated and solved the issue - see the updated answer.

Comment: I updated question with your solution, but problems remain. When you replicated the problem did you also try it with scripts and style files?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz You're right, I just checked. This solves the `ng-src` issue, but causes the scripts and CSS references to be ignored. I'm having a play with the usemin task from the default yeoman `generator-angular` - seems to be a bug!

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I've got it working - let me know if you experience other issues :)

Comment: Works ^_^ +1 for being awesome and for taking your time :) Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

if you use some curly brackets to the beginning of your ngSrc directive value. You must to use the regex above in your Gruntfile.

```js
/<img[^\>]*[^\>\S]+ng\-src=['"][\{\}\:\w\s]*([^'"\)#]+)(#.+)?["']/gm
```